# How can I partially specialize class template non-type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, class-template

My question is pretty basic. I'm trying to give myself a convenience class template instantiation that does something mathematically intuitive. I want to be able to instantiate a class called `Q<0,31>` by instantiating it as `Q<31>`. According to cppreference.com, this [should be possible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```
template<class T> 
class A<int, T*, 5> {}; // #3: partial specialization where T1 is int, I is 5,
                        //     and T2 is a pointer
```

But when I try this:

```
template< unsigned integral, unsigned fractional >
class Q: public Signed<integral + fractional + 1u> {};

// There's a shorthand for Q notation where you don't specify the number of integer bits, and it's assumed to be 0
template< unsigned fractional > class  Q<0u, fractional>: public Signed<fractional + 1> {};

static_assert( std::is_same< Q<31>, Q<0,31> >::value, "Partial specialization should be equivalent to no integer component");
```

then I get an error saying I haven't passed enough template arguments

Comment: Seems lot of unnecessary code to confuse the readers. Just put what you have and what you want. `Q<31>` cannot be interpreted naturally to `Q<0,31>`, because the default arguments start from the left side.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the link. The partial specialization does not change how you specify the template arguments, it replaces the definition of the class that is instantiated when the provided arguments match the partial specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specializations are not overloads.  They are pattern matching.

There is no way to "overload" a template like you want, short of magic values.

```
template< unsigned fractional >
class  Q<0u, fractional>
```

this just pattern matches.

Your arguments are *always*

```
template< unsigned integral, unsigned fractional >
class Q
```

and your specialization matches when someone passes `0u` for `integral`.  So it matches

```
Q<0u, fractional>
```

it does *not* match

```
Q<fractional>
```

now, as mentioned, you can do this with magic values:

```
template< unsigned integral, unsigned fractional=-1 >
class Q
template< unsigned fractional >
class Q<fractional, -1>:Q<0u, fractional> {}
```

but that also happens if someone passes `-1` manually.

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you'll be able to have user defined types as template non-type template parameters, so you could do something like:

```
template< unsigned A, optional<unsigned> B = {} >
class Q;

template< unsigned integral, unsigned fractional >
class Q< integral, optional<unsigned>(fractional) > // 2 arg case

template< unsigned fractional >
class Q< fractional, nullopt >:Q<0u, fractional> {}; // 1 arg case
```

but that isn't here yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it the way you want it, because as already said is not and overload, but it's possibile with a alias template with a partial specialization:

```
template<int, int B>
struct Q {};

template<int B>
using Q0 = Q<0,B>;
```

in your code

```
static_assert( std::is_same< Q0<31>, Q<0,31> >::value, "Partial specialization should be equivalent to no integer component");
```

this will compile with no error